# python solving Ax=b and inverse

Tags: python, linear-algebra

```
m = 10
n = 10
d = 10
np.random.seed(0)
M = np.random.randn(m *n,1 )

A = np.random.randn(d, m* n)

b = A.dot(M)
print(M)
print(np.linalg.pinv(A).dot(b))
```

could someone please tell my why these 2 prints do not produce the sameanswer?

Comment: Generally, float arithmetic isn't exact, therefore results may differ depending on the way they were calculated even if they are mathematically equal.

Comment: The example you give would be easier to parse conceptually if you simplified it some, i.e. you have two variables determining your number of unknowns when one would suffice. Also you call the unknown vector `M` when `x` is more common and you use `x` in your title.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is [under-determined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system) - you have fewer equations (`d=10`) than unknowns (`m*n=100`), since your A matrix (of size `(10,100)`) has fewer rows than columns. In this case you cannot generally expect to get a unique solution, there could be infinitely many. If you're looking for a better way to approach these computations, [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nla.2127) looks like a promising reference.